# How to handle inline code with RequireJS Optimization

Tags: javascript, asp.net, requirejs

How should I handle inline code when using [RequireJS Optimization](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html)?

Along with bunch of separate JavaScript files that are being loaded via RequireJS, I have an object defined within my ASPX file.

```
<script>
    define('PageData', function(){
        return {
            target: <%=_target%>,
            permissions: <%=_permissions%>
        };
    });
</script>
```

This object contains page load data and is required by many of my files.

Of course, when I try to use Optimization, it complains because it cannot find neither a module defined as PageData nor a file called PageData.js.

Is there a way to ignore this dependency?

Comment: http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty should help. Use a path for the `PageData` module and use the **'empty:' scheme**. But ideally you would not have module definitions in a HTML page.

Comment: Thanks, @PaulGrime. That did the trick. For the long term solution, I will see if we can pull that definition out of the HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PaulGrime comments, `empty:` does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Got answer from jrburke and it works for me.

https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/867

> Use the "empty:" paths config option in the build to allow the optimization to complete:
>
> http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty